# По форуму phpbb

Tags: php, phpbb

После регистрации на форуме phpbb пишет ошибку:

```
phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [ROOT]/phpbb/filesystem/filesystem.php on line 838: is_link(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home) is not within the allowed path(s): 
/home/intern48/nicedayz.site/www:/home/intern48/.system/tmp:/usr/local/pear)
[phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [ROOT]/phpbb/filesystem/filesystem.php on 
line 875: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/) is not 
within the allowed path(s):
(/home/intern48/nicedayz.site/www:/home/intern48/.system/tmp:/usr/local/pear)
 [phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file [ROOT]/phpbb/filesystem/filesystem.php on line 880: is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home) is not 
within the allowed path(s): (/home/intern48/nicedayz.site/www:/home/intern48/.system/tmp:/usr/local/pear)
```

В чём причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставь в параметре **open_basedir** значение **none**

В конфиге httpd.conf или в панели сервера если таковая есть.

Comment: Спасибо!На хостинге установил значение open_basedir = 0 Ошибка исчезла.